# Display Excerpt from Category post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display an excerpt from a post within a category in a testimonials slider. I have the above code, and I am customizing the posts using Advanced Custom Fields to display an avatar, name and a quote. I am adding the code to footer.php where there the slider exists, but the posts appearing are the ones in the 'Uncategorized' section. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php $posts = query_posts('cat=testimonials&showposts=1'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: tried the following also but didn't work:  `code` <?php $posts = get_posts('orderby=rand&numberposts=1cat=22'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>
<p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
  query_posts('cat=testimonials&showposts=1');
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  the_excerpt();
  endwhile;
```

query_posts('cat=testimonials&showposts=1');

or try

query_posts('cat=CATID&showposts=1');
CATID >> Replace with your cat id

***Updated Answer***

Then try instead query_posts with get_post

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => -1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ){ echo $post->post_excerpt; }
```

may be help you...

Comment: <ul>
<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ){